# express app.get function gives "Argument types do not match parameters" error

Tags: typescript, ide, webstorm, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

The following code...

```
app.get('/basic', (req, res) => {
    res.send({message: 'hello'})
})
```

generates a message `Argument types do not match parameters` in WebStorm 2016.2.4

[image: Argument types do not match parameters]

The relevant dependencies section in my `package.json` is:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@types/body-parser": "0.0.32",
  "@types/express": "^4.0.33",
  "@types/lodash": "^4.14.34",
  "@types/node": "^6.0.38",
  "body-parser": "1.15.1",
  "dotenv": "2.0.0",
  "express": "4.13.4",
  "lodash": "^4.13.1",
  "typescript": "^2.0.3"
},
```

When I remove the `@types/express` package, WebStorm no longer gives the error message, but the TypeScript compiler gives a `error TS2307: Cannot find module 'express'` message.

Is there a way to configure this differently or is WebStorm just playing catch-up with TypeScript 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT: This solved itself in Webstorm v2016.3.1**

---

Before that, a partial solution I had discovered was adding type declarations in the following fashion:

```
import * as express from 'express'

const app : express.Application | express.Router = express()
```

Comment: Still a problem with WebStorm v2017.1.4. No error when editing from Visual Studio Code though. For the meantime, I uses the definition from typings (`typings install express --save`) instead of from yarn/npm itself (`yarn add @types/express`). Cannot give up WebStorm :)

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue. Problem is I installed the typings from dt/express via `typings install dt~express` and when I looked at the type definition of .get() at the express/index.ts file, there was a mismatch:

```
get: {(name: string): any;} & IRouterMatcher<this>;
```

This was not what I wanted, and I instead did a `typings install express` to get the type definitions from npm/express.

My `typings.json` file looks like this:

```
{
"dependencies": {
    "express": "registry:npm/express#4.14.0+20160925001530"
  },
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It looks like it might be specific to TypeScript 1 though.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript is unable to find declarations of inner objects properly - 
Instead of importing express in it entirety and accessing its subobjects, e.g.:

```
import * as express from "express";
...
public app: express.Application;
```

Do

```
import { NextFunction, Application, Router } from "express";
...
public app: Application;
```